# django-extensions shell_plus autoload

Tags: django

How do I tell django-extensions' `shell_plus` what models I want to autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past whenever shell_plus wasn't autoloading my models it was normally because there was an error in the models and it was causing the autoloading to fail.

If you open shell plus and then try to manually load your modules one at a time what happens?

```
from app.models import ModelName
```

Another thing to try is to turn off all of the apps except for the default django apps in the settings file, and see if they autoload just fine. If they do, then slowly add more and more apps, one at a time, until it stops working, then you can find out which model is having issues. Once you know which model is having issues, it will make it easier to find out what is going on.

The most common error I had was a cyclical dependency between two different models (this model depends on that model, but it wasn't loaded yet, and vice versa).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> **shell_plus** – An enhanced version of
>   the Django shell. It will autoload all
>   your models making it easy to work
>   with the ORM right away.

Quote from django-extensions github wiki located https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/wiki/Current-Command-Extensions

Don't believe its actually changeable its designed to quickly autoload *ALL* models.

Comment: For me it doesn't load any of my models.

Comment: @Jason-Swett, You probably have an issue with one of your models, and this is causing them not to load correctly. Look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a new patch for the shell_plus extension that makes it possible to ignore some models. Waiting for https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/pull/99 to get accepted.

Comment: Forgot to update my post, but this patch is in the upstream release now. :)

Answer (score 0):

according to the [code](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py). shell_plus always loading all your models.

Answer (score 0):

By default `shell_plus` always loads all your models.
Thanks to @xeor you can use the option *SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD* in your settings to skip some of your models.
You can also configure aliases to your models to avoid names collisions.

More details:
http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html?highlight=shell_plus#configuration